# JsonConverter StringEnumConverter shows the first value for all items

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

While drinking my morning coffee I stumbled upon a bug I coudn't quite figure out.
I am trying to serialize an Enum by it's EnumMember Value

As shown here

```
    public enum LocationStatus
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "Open")]
    Open = 0,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Closed")]
    Closed = 1,

    [EnumMember(Value = "On Hold")]
    OnHold = 2,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Closed Test")]
    ClosedTest = 3,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Open Test")]
    OpenTest = 4,

    [EnumMember(Value = "Under Construction")]
    UnderConstruction = 5
}
```

And here

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string LocationAddress { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Status")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public LocationStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ConnectionPoint> ConnectionPoints { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem is it only give the first value, I got database entries with 0, 1 and 2 but I get Open returned for all of them.

```
{
$id: "5",
LocationId: 3,
LocationName: "Legoland",
LocationAddress: "Nordmarksvej 9, 7190, Billund",
Longitude: 8.883983,
Latitude: 55.94971,
Status: "Open",
Created: "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
Organization: {
$id: "6",
OrganizationId: 3,
OrganizationName: "Lego.inc",
Locations: null,
Users: null
},
ConnectionPoints: null
},
{
$id: "7",
LocationId: 4,
LocationName: "BLiS Reijerwaard",
LocationAddress: "Pesetastraat 40, 2991 XT, Barendrecht",
Longitude: 4.547588,
Latitude: 51.872464,
Status: "Open",
Created: "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000",
Organization: {
$id: "8",
OrganizationId: 4,
OrganizationName: "BLiS",
Locations: null,
Users: null
},
ConnectionPoints: null
},
```

Does anybody know why this would happen? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hey i think problem is on > Created as its json format and you have passed time with it. so in time you will get " : ", so its getting manipulate. try with removing only time portion.

Comment: That was indeed not a good habit habit of me, but it doesn't change it

Comment: another thing $id should not be there.

Comment: That is used for referencing, but removing that also doesn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem - the enum is serialized and deserialized successfully.  Here is a fiddle showing the code I used: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fCUft4.  Note that the fiddle itself does not compile because apparently dotnetfiddle doesn't link with System.Runtime.Serialization.dll - but it works fine in my Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for this?